# How to get callback from PyQt6 QWebEnginePage().runJavaScript(js_code, callback)

Tags: javascript, python, pyqt6, qwebengineview

I am currently learning PyQt6 and I am interested in learning more about the capabilities of QtWebEngine. I would appreciate if you could recommend some guides or tutorials for studying QtWebEngine. Thank you in advance for your help.
I understand that the issue lies in the fact that the img tag does not appear on the web page in time for the JavaScript findElementByClassName method to find it.

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl
import sys

def js_handle_callback(result):
    print('Result: ', type(result), result)

js_code = """
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('lnXdpd');
canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
var base64String = canvas.toDataURL();
base64String;
"""

def js_run():
    page.runJavaScript(js_code, js_handle_callback)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QWebEngineView()
    page = view.page()
    page.loadFinished.connect(js_run)
    view.load(QUrl('https://google.com'))
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Output:

```
Result:  <class 'NoneType'> None
```

Tried to use signal `loadFinished`, but it doesn't help. The JavaScript window.addEventListener('load', function(){ My Code }) also doesn't help because the callback doesn't wait for the 'load' event.

Comment: (1) It is [off-topic on SO to request recommendations for tutorials, guides, books, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance/417480#417480). You can easily search for those yourself. See also: [ask]. (2) You should subclass QWebEnginePage and reimplement [javaScriptConsoleMessage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebenginepage.html#javaScriptConsoleMessage) so you can print javascript errors and console.log messages. (3) The script very likely fails because the image loading is blocked by google's cookie settings dialog.